# What type of functions have an average rate of change thats the same as the derivative?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I assume this applies to linear functions (y=mx+c), but are there other functions that fit this description?

Comment: No, only linear functions have that property for all intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for differentiable function that satisfies

$$\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}=f^{\prime}(x_{0})=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}\qquad (1)$$
for every $x_{0}$.

As user247327 commented, only linear functions 
satisfy (1) because, unlike nonlinear functions, they have the linear representation
$f(x)=f(x_{0})+(x-x_{0})f^{\prime}((x_{0})$ at every point $x_{0}$.

Intuitively, linear functions are the only functions with the property that the slope of the tangent at every point equals the slope of every secant (chord) passing through that point.

Comment: Your question really doesn't make sense.  The "average" rate of change is necessarily over some interval while the derivative is defined at individual points.  Even if you were to give a specific interval, at what point is the derivative to be evaluated?